# ECDSA signature verification in Golang using secp256r1/scep384r1/secp521r1 performance difference

Tags: go, digital-signature, sha256, ecdsa, secp256r1

I am using Golang to verify digital signatures, signed by ECDSA keys with secp256r1/scep384r1/secp521r1.

The difference in signature verification performance for secp256r1/scep384r1/secp521r1 is shocking.

For Digital signatures which are signed by **key secp256r1**, Golang is able to **verify around 27k signatures per second**.

For signatures which are signed by **key secp384r1**, it is able to **verify around 1700 signatures per second** and for signatures which are signed by **key of secp521r1**, **just 350 signatures are being verified per second**.

The difference in verification of digital signature is really huge, **signature algorithm is same for all three cases i.e. SHA256withECDSA.**

Sample code which is being used to verify signatures:

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/ecdsa"
    "crypto/sha256"
    "encoding/asn1"
    "encoding/base64"
    "encoding/json"
    "errors"
 //   "fmt"
    "math/big"
   "sync/atomic"
)

type ECDSASignature struct {
    R, S *big.Int
}

type Envelope struct {
    RawMessage json.RawMessage `json:"message"`
    Message    interface{}     `json:"-"`
    Signature  string          `json:"signature"`
}

func hash(b []byte) []byte {
    h := sha256.New()
    h.Write(b)
    return h.Sum(nil)
}

func (e *Envelope) Validate(publicKey *ecdsa.PublicKey) bool{
    der, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(e.Signature)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    sig := &ECDSASignature{}
    _, err = asn1.Unmarshal(der, sig)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    h := hash(e.RawMessage)
    valid := ecdsa.Verify(
        publicKey,
        h,
        sig.R,
        sig.S,
    )
    return valid 
}
```

Am I missing something here? Do I need to handle secp384r1 & secp521r1 differently for verifying signatures? How can I improve performance for verification of these signatures? Is it an expected behavior in Golang for these key types?

Comment: have you tried `openssl speed ecdsap256 ecdsap384 ecdsap521` for comparison? The order of magnitude different between 256 and 384 is not unusual. Or search for [sample results](https://www.silicom-usa.com/silicom-pe3isco3-ecc-performance-tests-with-intel-8955/) out there.

Comment: @Marc Thanks for pointing to this. You just saved a day. :) I am glad that it's a usual behavior.

Comment: It might be worth asking this on the golang-nuts mailing list.

Comment: @Marc, I used multi core and these are the numbers I got for my machine:
256 bits ecdsa (nistp256)   0.0000s   0.0000s 552855.5 163878.5
 384 bits ecdsa (nistp384)   0.0001s   0.0000s  15108.3  20175.4
 521 bits ecdsa (nistp521)   0.0002s   0.0001s   6346.4   8970.1
There is a huge difference in 8970 and 350 though I am utilizing all core in both the programs.

Comment: [Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14877425) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65423278) saying "P256 curve has optimized implementations for arm64 and amd64:https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/121360/"

Comment: Thanks for the update. My requirements were to process all three EC curves signatures efficiently. I noticed that NodeJs has a capability to do so and it's performance is equivalent to Openssl on multiple cores. I switched to NodeJs for now until Golang is optimized for secp384r1 & secp521r1.